# How long does it take to scan for Windows 7 updates after fixing Windows Update?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

When Windows Update fails to download updates, it is often recommended to run the Microsoft FixIt located at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971058

After running the FixIt, how long is it necessary to wait for Windows 7 to complete a check for updates (during a manual update scan)?

Should it just take a few minutes, or does it take hours?

Comment: this will vary by machine

Comment: @Keltari Can you write an answer that explains what causes this variance?

Answer (score 2):

After running the above referenced Microsoft FixIt, it can take Windows Update over an hour to scan for updates.

I can find no documentation from Microsoft that reveals this essential piece of information.